# IfModule itk.c ignored even if I'm running Apache itk

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm running itk as Apache MPM.

In order to prevent error in case I need to change the MPM in the future, I set

```
    <IfModule itk.c>
        AssignUserID user group
    </IfModule>
```

but I found that it gets ignored. In fact, if I add a `WTF` like and run `rcapache2 configtest` it returns me `Syntax OK`

```
    <IfModule itk.c>
        AssignUserID user group
        WTF ##doesn't throw error
    </IfModule>
```

By the way, `/etc/sysconfig/apache2` shows `APACHE_MPM="itk"`

How do I check if I'm running itk or not?

**EDIT:** If I remove the `ifmodule` and restart I get

```
Invalid command 'WTF', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

Comment: Remove the `ifmodule` condition and see if it throws an error. Looks like the module isn't actually loaded.

Comment: Tried. rcapache2 configtest throws exception

Comment: And the exception is ...

Comment: Invalid command 'WTF', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it throws an error when `IfModule` is commented out, then Apache doesn't think the `itk.c` module is actually loaded (so its not parsing the contents of the conditional statement).

But that is not to say that the `itk` module isn't actually being loaded. Otherwise, you would likely also have a an exception being thrown for `AssignUserID` too.

This isn't the first time I've come across Apache mis-reading the `.c`/`.h` files and thinking a module isn't loaded, *when it actually is*.

To know if its *actually* running - just check your `vhost` user in `top`/`ps`

Eg. `ps axu | grep -E '(apache|httpd)'`

Comment: It **is** actually running and assigning User ID. So shouldn't I just care about that all? I mean, I asked this question because I wanted to *put a switch* on the AssignUserId, not make sure that itk was actually working (because I knew)

Comment: I don't understand your question then. You asked how you could verify if `itk` was running - and why your edits weren't showing an error on `configtest`. I explained how to test your edits and how to test if `itk` was working ... what else do you want/need to know?

Comment: "How to let Apache test if itk is enabled?". Do I need a different <IfModule> clause? I need this in the case I need to switch to a different MPM because I have several vhosts that would then need to be all modified. Now that I re-read the question I find I missed this part

Comment: Ah. Now I understand. Try `<IfModule mpm_itk_module>`

Comment: This works!!!!!